# How to validate max post size on custom form

Tags: drupal, drupal-9, drupal-form-validation

I have a custom module with a multiple managed file upload.

```
        $form['attachments'] = [
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#multiple' => true,
            '#upload_validators' => [
                'file_validate_extensions' => ['jpg docx pdf xlsx jpeg png gif'],
                'file_validate_size' => [10485760],
            ],
       ];
```

When uploading one file that is more then 10MB it gives via AJAX the correct error that a file can not be larger then 10MB. That works out of the box.

How can I limit the total MB of all files that can be uploaded via this form?

For example:
3 files of 3MB = fine
4 files of 3MB = error.

I have managed to show a message when that happens

```
    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $max_size = 10485760;
        $total_size = 0;
        $triggered_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
        if($triggered_element['#name'] == 'attachments_upload_button') {
            $fids = (array) $form_state->getValue('attachments', []);
            if(!empty($fids)) {
                $files = File::loadMultiple($fids);
                foreach ($files as $key => $uploadedFile) {
                    $total_size += $uploadedFile->getSize();
                    if($total_size > $max_size) {
                        $form_state->setErrorByName('attachments', $this->t('The total maximum size of your file sizes can not be more than 10MB.'));
                        $form_state->set('attachments',array_pop($fids));
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I can not seem to remove the last uploaded file. It is still there and it is submitted on form submit. A part from the message, the code does not hold the form from submitting.

I want the last submitted file where the total of all files is > 10M to be removed from the form_state and also the tmp server folder. And ideally via AJAX without loss of field input.

I can't find a solution.
Thanks in advance.

How can I achieve this via ajax.

Ok, turns out it was not that difficult.
With upload validators it is possible to add variables. So I added $form_state as a variable to a custom upload validator.

```
        $form['attachments'] = [
            '#type' => 'managed_file',
            '#multiple' => true,
            '#upload_validators' => [
                'file_validate_extensions' => ['jpg docx pdf xlsx jpeg png gif'],
                'file_validate_size' => [10485760],
                'size_max_upload' => [$form_state],
            ],
        ];
```

And wrote a custom validator function

```
/**
 * Validate maximum size upload.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\file\FileInterface $file
 *   File object.
 *
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
 *   Form state object.
 * 
 * @return array
 *   Errors array.
 */
function size_max_upload(File $file, &$form_state) {
  $errors = [];
  $max_size = 10485760;
  $total_size = $file->getSize();
  $triggered_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();

  if($triggered_element['#name'] == 'attachments_upload_button') {
    $fids = (array) $form_state->getValue('attachments', []);
  
    if(!empty($fids)) {
      $files = File::loadMultiple($fids);
  
      foreach ($files as $key => $uploadedFile) {
        $total_size += $uploadedFile->getSize();
  
        if($total_size > $max_size) {
          $errors[] = t("The total maximum size of your file sizes can not be more than 10MB.");
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return $errors;
}
```

Comment: Why not you can just use the array_pop($fids) to pop the last element and use $form_state->setValue('attachments', $fids) in submitForm() handler?

Comment: @HarishST. Removing the item on submit does not give the user the notification that his last file is removed. I want to capture it on upload so the user can see what files are sent and what files not. I'm looking for the same way like 'file_validate_size'. if the file is larger, the file will not be uploaded and a warning is displayed. But that procedure is only on one file level. Not the whole field.

Comment: I edited the question with a solution.

Comment: When you find the solution to your own question.  Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.  This also has the benefit of helping you're own reputation on the site.

Comment: @Bee_Riii for answering my own question I need a rep of at least 15. But I will remember that. Thank you.